# Sniff ethernet communication

Tags: networking, wireshark, sniffing, man-in-the-middle

I have a setup in which I'm connected to a switch and there are 2 more devices there. Just protocol converters ... that have recently stopped working.

Since this equipment doesn't have any type of diagnostics or a way to show me what's going on between them I don't have any clue as to what's actually wrong (configurations are right ... I at least know that they are exchanging packets with each other).

I tried to exchange one of them for a device I made on my own, but I get what could be considered very bizarre results sometimes ... some packets come Ok and many others are completely bizarre.

Is there a way in which I can do a man in the middle or some other way to sniff the communication? There are 4 parts in the system and neither is giving me any output on what might be wrong.

OBS: There are no wireless devices, only cabled ethernet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are ways to sniff Ethernet traffic. Pretty much any *managed* switch, even a little 5-port (~US$40) or 8-port (~US$60) one, will usually have a way to do port mirroring so that any traffic being sent or received on a given port is also sent out an additional "mirror" port so you can hook up a sniffer (e.g. PC/Mac running Wireshark or tcpdump) to the mirror port and capture the traffic.

Comment: Thank you so much. Port mirroring .. didn't know that ... gonna try that. Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: There are other options than a managed switch, such as a TAP (or even a hub as a last resort).  My answer to a recent question provides links to more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932867/tcpdump-wireshark-capturing-problems/54937562#54937562